# Relationship from relationship Model Query Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a question as to how I can recover a relationship within another relationship using SEQUELIZE in NODEJS.

Example, in Laravel PHP I can do something like this:

```
Model::with(['character.genetic'])->get()
```

That way it will bring the relationship of "Character" and the relationship that "Character has with Genetic", however, how can I do that in NODE?

Below is an example of my code in NodeJS:

```
let data = await PlayerCharacter.findAll({
        include: ['character.genetic'], ///dont works
        where: {
          playerId: req.playerId,
        },
        order: [
          ['levelId', 'desc']
        ]
      });
```

My class Main

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import database from '../database';

const PlayerCharacter = database.define('player_characters', {
    .....
    characterId: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    .....
});

/**
 * Relationships
 */

PlayerCharacter.belongsTo(Character, {
    foreignKey: 'characterId',
    as: 'character',
});

export default PlayerCharacter;
```

My Class Character

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import database from '../database';

const Character = database.define('characters', {
    ...
    geneticId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
   ....
}, {
    timestamps: false,
});

/**
 * Relationships
 */

Character.hasOne(CharacterGenetic, {
    foreignKey: 'geneticId',
    as: 'genetic',
});

export default Character;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested `include` option like this:

```js
let data = await PlayerCharacter.findAll({
        include: [{
          model: Character,
          as: 'character',
          include: [{
            model: CharacterGenetic,
            as: 'genetic'
          }  
          ]
        }
        ],
        where: {
          playerId: req.playerId,
        },
        order: [
          ['levelId', 'desc']
        ]
      });
```